# Random Hidden Div's with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, random, hide, selector

I have a question about javascript. My problem is that I have 9 div containers and an selector () with numbers from 1 to 9. What I would like to have is ONE function that chooses the quantity, which is chosen in the selector, and hides the number of divs with the visibility option. The function should really should hide the number of the selector and not that the function hides two times the same random div. The divs are in one class and have the ids like id1, id2 and id3.

Hope you understand anything, because my English really sucks in this topic.

Thanks
Nicolas

Comment: Can you show some code please?

Comment: which part should i show you?

Comment: a section of the html code that shows how it works, and the javascript function you are currently trying to use. Using [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) also helps

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/u4UJJ/
Here it is!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9Hppw/ Better version

Comment: Thanks. You should also post the code in the question, which will help make it clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some bugs in your code:

```
if (zahl[y].style.visibility = 'hidden') {
```

You need `document.getElementById(zahl[y])` rather than just `zahl[y]`, and you need to use `==` to compare values rather than `=`. Also, you are setting the visibility to hidden *then* checking whether it is hidden, when presumably you want to do it the other way around. And,

```
i - 1;
```

should be `i--;`. If you fix these, the code will work, as [shown here](http://jsfiddle.net/9Hppw/1/).

However some further improvements are also possible - no need to define all of the indices when you could use `getElementsByClassName`.

```
function hide(anzahl) {
    var cubes = document.getElementsByClassName('cube');
    for (var i = 0; i < cubes.length; i++) {
        cubes[i].style.visibility = '';
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < anzahl;) {
        var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
        if (cubes[y].style.visibility == '') {
            cubes[y].style.visibility = 'hidden';
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Hppw/2/)